# Custom dock icon reverts whenever the app is open

Tags: macos, dock, icon

I have changed the Dock icon for an app and it shows the new icon only when the app is not open.  But as soon as I open it, the old icon comes back. When I close the app, the new icon appears again. I have tried pinning an alias to the Dock, but the same thing happens. It shows correctly in other places, such as Finder and Launchpad.

I have tried the following ways of changing the icon:

- Copied the new image onto the info window.
- Replaced the favicon.icns file in the package contents
- Restarted the Dock and Finder several times
- Cleared the icon cache by executing:

  ```
  rm /var/folders/*/*/*/com.apple.dock.iconcache;killall Dock
  ```

I know the cache has updated because the icon for Pages, which I had uninstalled but hadn't unpinned from the Dock, changed to a question mark.

The app is YouTube to MP3 by MediaHuman.

How do I stop the icon from reverting? I am running macOS Sierra 10.12.6.

Comment: **What application is it?** I've seen this behavior with some apps, can't remember which, and the app itself was dynamically changing the Dock Tile and nothing the user could do about it. This may be the case for the app in question. (Which is presently unknown to us.)

Comment: Have you tried changing the icon via Show Package Contents/Resources/App.icons?

Comment: @user3439894  It is YouTube to MP3 by MediaHuman (I just edited it into the post as well).  Maximus, yes, I replaced the .icns file, which makes it a bit interesting that it is still able to use the old image anyway.